# Equivalent Android to this php crypt function

Tags: php, android, encryption, blowfish

i have to generate on Android the same crypted key as this php function:
I have test many method (argument cipher instance) but i have never the same result.
How can we reproduce this following function on android?

PHP:

```
$data = str_pad($string_to_encrypt, 16, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT );
    $data = pack('H' . strlen($data), $data);


    $iv = str_pad("0123456789ABCDEF", 16, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT );
    $key = str_pad("01234567", 8, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT );

    $key = pack('H' . strlen($key), $key);
    $iv = pack('H' . strlen($iv), $iv);


        //ciphermode, key, data, mode, iv
    $baDataCiphered=mcrypt_cbc (MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $data, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT, $iv);

    return strToHex($baDataCiphered);
```

Comment: you got this error from php side or android side ?

Comment: php works. i have to do the same crypt in android side

Comment: Blowfish, DES and AES are completely different block ciphers. Please don't confuse them.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that `AES` does not support 8 bytes keys, it's only support 16, 24 and 32 bytes .

while you are providing 8 bytes key `01234567`

so you will need to change your key length -maybe pad it- into 16 bytes.

> AES is a variant of Rijndael which has a fixed block size of 128 bits,
>   and a key size of 128, 192, or 256 bits.

in this case, you will face new problem with `DES` which is support only 8 bytes key length.

> The key is nominally stored or transmitted as 8 bytes, each with odd
>   parity.

but as alternative, you may use `ThreeDES` instead, which is use 8*3 (24) key length which i think that it won't conflict with AES.

---

However, you need to keep in mind the deprecation of [mcrypt_cbc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-cbc.php) function.

> ### Warning
>
> This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.5.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.